# Ambiguous/rvalue arguments cause compiler to choose incorrect overload

Tags: c++, overloading, rvalue, ambiguous

I have a home grown template class called `Vec` which is a pale shadow of: `std::vector<T>`

To avoid re-inventing the wheel the header overloads for `assign` are copied from: `std::vector::assign`

[image]

..so

[image]

As part of testing `Str` class, ..test code is also run against `std::vector<T>` to ensure equivalent output...

If `std::vector<T>` is used then compiler will choose the correct overload:

[image]

However, when `Vec<T>` is used then compiler insists on choosing the incorrect overload:

[image]

There is an obvious work around via casting the args to lvalues prior to use:

[image]

Question:
Given that both `Vec<T>` and `std::vector<T>` use identical header overloads for their respective `assign` ...how is `std::vector<T>` able to implement rvalues arg without confusing the compiler?

Comment: Show us the code in question, and not what you assume/expect it to be.

Comment: The post already shows the code in question.  I've made no assumptions & have no expectations.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] of **your** implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[sequence.reqmts]/14** For every sequence container defined in this Clause and in Clause 21:
>
> (14.2) — If the member functions of the forms:
>
> ```
> template <class InputIterator> // such as insert()
> rt fx1(const_iterator p, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> template <class InputIterator> // such as append(), assign()
> rt fx2(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> template <class InputIterator> // such as replace()
> rt fx3(const_iterator i1, const_iterator i2, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> ```
>
> are called with a type `InputIterator` that does not qualify as an input iterator, then these functions shall not participate in overload resolution.

This is typically implemented with a touch of SFINAE. You can check the headers of your favorite standard library implementation for details.